# Segmentation fault when using strcmp in c

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

I get segmentation fault when using strcmp like this

```
bool str_in_arr(char* str, char** sarr){
    int res = false;
    int i = 0;

    while(strcmp(sarr[i], "\0")){
        if(!strcmp(str, sarr[i])){
            res = true;
            goto out;
        }
        i++;
    }

    out:
    return res;
}
```

and I call it like this

```
char* keywords[] = {"int", "return", "\0"};
char wrd[256] = "";

// ... some code that make wrd = "int", with null terminators

str_in_arr(wrd, keywords);
```

I tryed using gdb and I found that this line `if(!strcmp(str, sarr[i])){` gives error

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strlen_avx2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S:65
65      ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S: No such file or directory.
```

I also checked if `char** sarr` is null terminated and it is

## Update

main.c

```
#include "util.h"
#include "lexer.h"

#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char* code = 
    "int main() { \
    return 2; \
    }";
    struct Token* tokens = malloc(sizeof(struct Token) * 100);
    lex(code, tokens);
    return 0;
}
```

lexer.c

```
#include "lexer.h"
#include "util.h"

#include <string.h>

int toki;

int lex(char* code, struct Token* tokens){
    char* keywords[] = {"int", "return", "\0"};


    int res = 0;
    int c_offset = 0; // code_offset
    int line = 0;
    toki = 0;

    while(code[c_offset] != '\0'){
        char wrd[256] = "";
        int i = 0;
        while(code[c_offset + i] != '\0' && code[c_offset + i] != ' ' && code[c_offset + i] != '\n' && code[c_offset + i] != '\r'){
            if(i > 256){
                printf("Error too big token, max size 256 characters: %d: %s\n", line, wrd);
                res = -1;
                goto out;
            }
            wrd[i] = code[c_offset + i];
            i++;
        }
        if(code[c_offset + i] == '\n' || code[c_offset + i] == '\r'){
            line++;
        }
        i++;
        c_offset += i;

        if(str_in_arr(wrd, keywords)){
            tokens[toki].tokenType = KEYWORD;
            tokens[toki].value = wrd;
            tokens[toki].line = line;
            toki++;
        }
        else{
            //printf("sad\n");
        }

        printf("%s\n", tokens[toki].value);
    }

    out:
    return res;
}
```

util.c

```
#include "util.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* file_read(const char* path) {
    // Create a file
    FILE* file = fopen(path, "r");
    if (!file) {
        printf("Could not open file '%s'\n", path);
        return NULL;
    }

    // Get the file size
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    int size = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    // Read file
    char* buf = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (size + 1));
    if (!buf) {
        printf("Could not allocate memory for file!\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    fread(buf, 1, size, file);
    buf[size] = '\0';
    fclose(file);

    // Return contents
    return buf;
}

bool str_in_arr(char* str, char** sarr){
    int res = false;
    int i = 0;

    while(strcmp(sarr[i], "\0")){
        if(!strcmp(str, sarr[i])){
            res = true;
            goto out;
        }
        i++;
    }

    out:
    return res;
}
```

lexer.h

```
#ifndef LEXER_H
#define LEXER_H

typedef enum{
    KEYWORD = 1,
    IDENTIFIER,
    CONSTANT,
    OPARENTHESIS,
    CPARENTHESIS,
    OBRACE,
    CBRACE,
    SEMICOLON
} TokenType;

struct Token{
    TokenType tokenType;
    char* value;
    int line;
};

int lex(char* code, struct Token* tokens);

#endif
```

util.h

```
#ifndef UTIL_H
#define UTIL_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

char* file_read(const char* path);
int ptrlen(void* ptr);
bool str_in_arr(char* str, char* sarr[]);

#endif
```

Comment: No `...` code please. Please provide complete code as a [mre]. That is, exact code that anyone can run exactly as shown to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also, note that a [mre] should include everything necessary to reproduce the problem, including a function `main` and all `#include` directives. If you are unable to reproduce the problem in a [mre], then the problem is probably somewhere else in your program.

Comment: Side note: Instead of `goto out;`, you can simply use the [`break`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/break) statement.

Comment: That is still not complete code. For example, there is no complete `main`. Please show the complete code as one block so that others can paste it exactly as shown into an editor, compile it and run it to see the problem.

Comment: The code you posted before your "update" [seems to work](https://godbolt.org/z/8aPYbonjc). It does not produce a segmentation fault and gcc's address sanitizer does not report anything wrong. Therefore, the problem is probably somewhere in the other code.

Comment: Sigh. Still not complete code. Not sure how else to explain what is needed. Make a minimal example, ensure it reproduces the problem then cut and paste the code **exactly** from your editor into the question. Don't leave anything out. Don't add anything. Don't change anything.

Comment: Ok I will add everything, sorry for waste of time

Comment: I suggest that you use a debugger to inspect the state of both function arguments of the `strcmp` call that is causing the segmentation fault. You already stated that you have verified that `char** sarr` is "null terminated", which probably means that it contains a pointer to an empty string as its last element. Did you also verify that all of the other pointers of `sarr` point to strings that are properly null-terminated? Also, did you verify that the first argument of `strcmp` (`str`) is properly null-terminated?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel yes, every `sarr` element has null terminator and also `str` has it

Comment: Your posted code relies on input from an external file. Could you change your program to use a small amount of hard-coded input, so that it does not rely on external input? That will make it easier for other people to reproduce the problem. Of course, before doing that, please verify that the hard-coded input actually reproduces the segmentation fault.

Comment: Updated and it does not work still, problem occurs on same place when i use gdb

Comment: One problem: `printf("%s\n", tokens[toki].value);` is accessing invalid memory as `toki` has been incremented after filling in the previous array entry.

Comment: `tokens[toki].value = wrd;` That also won't work in the way you intend. `wrd` is scoped only within one iteration of the `while` loop and becomes invalid as soon as the loop iteration ends. May not be the cause of your current crash but will definetely cause problems at some point.

Comment: For 2nd comment before: it is not important, it should be `toki - 1`
For previous comment: do you mean that it will be invalid because i am just puting pointer (to address of `wrd`) in `tokens[toki].value` instead of string value? I am quite new to c so i do some things wrong

Comment: @Jelka: Yes. `tokens[toki].value` will become a [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) as soon as the loop iteration ends. This means that it will be pointing to an object whose lifetime has ended, so it will no longer be pointing to a valid object.

Comment: Oh, thx i didn't realized that. so it should be `strcpy()` to copy _value_ of `wrd` to `tokens[toki].value`? i know this is little bit outside of question but thx for your time and help;
also i heard term dangling pointer just today or yesterday

Comment: @Jelka: Yes, in this case, you must make a copy of the actual string, instead of just of the pointer, so you must use `strcpy`. Note that you must also allocate sufficient memory for holding a copy of the string.